# Error: [$injector:modulerr] on Karma

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, phantomjs, mocha.js, karma-mocha

I am a newbie to testing with Karma and Mocha. I want to do a unit test on the following controller:

```
'use strict';

// common functionality
angular.module('app').controller('CommonCtrl', ['$scope', 'appConfig',
  function ($scope, appConfig) {
    $scope.$back = function() {
    window.history.back();
  };

  $scope.Currencies = appConfig.currencies;

  // todo: decide where this should go (appConfig?)
  $scope.ctPaginationLabel = {
    text: 'Einträge pro Seite:',
    of: 'von'
  }
}]);
```

This is what my test class looks like:

```
describe 'CommonCtrl', ->
  $controller = null    

  beforeEach ->
    module 'app'
    inject (_$controller_) ->
      $controller = _$controller_

  it 'error flag if scope is missing', ->
    $scope = null
    appConfig = null
    controller = $controller 'CommonCtrl', { $scope: $scope, appConfig: appConfig }
    controller.error.should.be.ok
```

But I get the following error:

```
27 11 2015 11:47:29.378:INFO [karma]: Karma v0.13.15 server started at http://localhost:9876/
27 11 2015 11:47:29.387:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
27 11 2015 11:47:31.715:INFO [PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket oF_wQ0cqLGkNs9cWAAAA with id 44252940
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) CommonCtrl "before each" hook for "error flag if scope is missing" FAILED
    Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Amodulerr%5D%20 ...
...
at /Users/Marcel/Development/project/html/js/angular/angular.min.js:38
    at m (/Users/Marcel/Development/project/html/js/angular/angular.min.js:7)
    at h (/Users/Marcel/Development/project/html/js/angular/angular.min.js:38)
    at fb (/Users/Marcel/Development/project/html/js/angular/angular.min.js:41)
    at workFn (/Users/Marcel/Development/project/test/helpers/angular-mocks.js:2427)
    at /Users/Marcel/Development/project/test/helpers/angular-mocks.js:2410
    at /Users/Marcel/Development/project/test/unit/controllers/common.js:9
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.014 secs / 0.006 secs)
```

I embedded all dependencies in **karma.conf.js**. Where is the mistake in my test class?

Comment: Where have you defined the 'app' module? angular.module('app', [])  ?

Comment: And probably use something like -                                                                                                                                          module(function($provide) {
      $provide.value('appConfig', null); // override injected dependency
 });                                                                                                           inside your 'it' block.

Comment: The 'app' module should be defined here: https://jsfiddle.net/marcellus123/aeqd12up/

Comment: I inserted `module ($provide) ->
  $provide.value 'appConfig', null
  return` in the `it` block but it does not solve the problem